# $AA^{\#}=A^{\#}A$ , Complex Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ **invertible** matrix of complex functions entries, with the property $AA^{\#}=A^{\#}A$  where $A^{\#}(z)=\left(\overline{A(\bar{z})} \right)^{T}$. Is it true that 
$$A B A^{\#}=A^{\#}BA$$
for any $n\times n$ complex matrix of functions $B$?

If not, when this result could be true?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. try 
$$ A = \pmatrix{z+i & z\cr z & z+i\cr},\ A^\# = \pmatrix{z-i & z\cr z & z-i\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr} $$